# What is the easiest way to write bits to a file in Python?

Tags: python, binary

I have an array of boolean values in python. How can I write these values to a file as binary, (where each value only requires 1 bit of data to save)?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536411/write-individual-bits-to-a-file-in-python) nearly identical question.

Comment: Or perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220916/writing-bits-to-a-binary-file) one.

Comment: [Bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.8.1) is what you're looking for: `bitarray.bitarray([False, True, True]).tofile(open("hello.txt","wb"))`